# Flex AdvancedDataGrid databind complete event

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, advanceddatagrid

Is there some way in Flex where I can tell when all of the data has finished binding to my AdvancedDataGrid? I have a bunch of label functions that run and I need to a busy cursor while the grid gets populated. I then want to remove it when it's all done. And also fire another event.

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself. The updateComplete event gets triggered every time the grid datasource gets updated.